# Crear una sección personalizada en "app.config" para luego leerlo

Tags: c#, xml, configuración

¿Cómo puedo crear una estructura *XML* en el *"app.config"* de mi aplicación para luego leerlo en forma de árbol? ¿Y ¿Cómo leerla?

Ejemplo de estructura:

```
<Variables>
     <Tipo nombre="Temperatura">
          <unidad>kelvin</unidad>
          <unidad>celcius</unidad>
     </Tipo>
     <Tipo nombre="Presión">
          <unidad>psi</unidad>
          <unidad>atm</unidad>
          <unidad>kgF/cm2</unidad>
     </Tipo>
</Variables>
```

Comment: Deberías especificar lenguaje de programación, además de lo que has hecho hasta el momento, después para guardar una estructura XML, lo recomendable es usar un archivo .xml (valga la redundancia)

Comment: lo que quieres es crear una seccion en el config, para esto se debe herear de [ConfigurationSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Para leer valores del archivo app.config:

```
using System.Configuration; // es necesario usar este ensamblado

string val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nombre"]; 
// donde nombre es una etiqueta en el archivo app.config
```

P.D.: No es bueno que incrustes codigo en el archivo app.config, este se usa para configuraciones de la aplicacion, te recomiendo que uses archivos o, tambien puedes almacenar tu codigo xml en una cadena, para luego procesarla.

Comment: Gracias @Paolo pero para lo que necesito me hace falta escribir en el app.config, porque lo que quiero escribir es configuracion de mi aplicacion, ademas ya sabia lo de ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["nombre"], pero quiero leer de forma jerarquica no pares key/value. Gracias de todas formas, ya pude resolver el problema con Linq to XML (using System.Xml.Linq)

Answer (score 1):

Crear una sección en la configuración es algo de lo más lógico y algo que yo suelo hacer en todas mis aplicaciones. Normalmente la documentación habla de como hacerlo en Web.config pero en App.config es exactamente igual.

Dependiendo de la versión de .NET que uses se hace una una forma u otra, como es un poco extenso te paso un enlace a la documentación de Microsoft.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Además para garantizar que el Xml es como el que necesitas, yo genero un XSD para poder validarlo, y después con la herramienta XSD.EXE genero una clase en .NET para manejarlo cómodamente.